# Call method when e-mail sent from Outlook?

Tags: .net, events, vba, outlook-2007, mapi

There's a VBA class called `MailItemClass` that has an [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220221(v=office.12).aspx) for when an e-mail has been sent in Outlook. I can't find this for VB.NET. I've looked through the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb610835(v=office.12).aspx) but I just can't find it in the `MAPI`.

(Can I call VBA from VB.NET?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you making an Outlook Add-in? There's an event called [Application.ItemSend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147641%28office.12%29.aspx) that is raised before an item is sent. I just launched VS2010, created a new project of type Outlook 2007 Add-in that contains just the below code and my `Application_ItemSend` fired as expected when I clicked Send from Outlook.

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub

    Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.ItemSend
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hi")
    End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT**

If you're making a WinForms app that you use the same method but you "see" it a little differently. What can be a little confusing is that the event is raised at the application level and not from the mail item itself.

```
Public Class Form1
    ''//Holds a reference to our mail application
    Private WithEvents OA As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ''//Either launches Outlook or snaps to the current running one
        OA = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OA_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles OA.ItemSend
        MessageBox.Show("Hello")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: No, I'm not creating an Outlook Add-in, maybe I should? I have a Windows Forms-project where I need to update a database once a created (via MAPI) e-mail has been sent.

Answer (score 0):

Both VBA and VB.NET use the "Outlook Object Model".  It is odd that the send event is omitted.  However, you still have this [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitemclass.itemevents_event_send%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

I'm not much of VB guy, but as MAPI is oriented to C++, using it from VB.net doesn't sound very streamlined, but the MailItem will roughly correspond to LPMESSAGE.  The various outlook addin frameworks have pretty good notification systems in place.  If you need go with MAPI alone, check MAPI [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc842079.aspx), ...but it's not easy.